# Administrative Tools Access Denied - Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

A newly built server 2012 R2 domain controller with the latest Windows updates. When I login with my domain admin account I get access denied if I try to access any of the Administrative tools. If I use the domain\administrator account everything works. Other system admin accounts have the same exact issue.

1. I have uninstalled AV.
2. Disabled UAC.
3. Disabled firewall.
4. The administrators and domain admins groups have full control on the C drive.
5. It seems that the problem started as soon as I installed and configured the Domain services role.

Error message:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

Comment: I rebuilt the server and once again, as soon as I install the Domain Services role and promote the server to a DC and reboot, I get that message right off the bat because it won't open server manager!

Comment: Reeves, thank you for trying to help. I think it has something to do with promoting the server to a DC. I guess I'm doing something wrong during the process. I didn't run adprep on the schema master before promoting the server and I wonder if that's the problem. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just finished fixing exactly the same issue. In my case, the security descriptor for root of C: drive was empty/corrupted.

I have added Administrators/Full Control to the drive and then set default permissions copying them from another DC.

Comment: Thank you! The thing is I had to cut my loses and rebuild the server which I did but this time I went with 2008 R2. Now I'm getting schema mismatch replication error!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else dealing with this should know that I added the Korean Language and was able to continue installing exchange 2016.  For some reason that worked.